# Variables created within a function not getting stored in data frame

Tags: r, function

I am writing a function to create some predicted variables within an existing data set that I am using to run some ML models. My function looks like this:

```
doall <- function(x1, x2){
  J48 <- J48(ML, data=df1)    
  #summary(J48)    
  X1 <- predict(J48, df1, type="class")   
  X2 <- predict(J48, df2, type="class")    
  #return(X1)   
   }    
doall(df1$DT_predict, df2$DT_predict1)
```

`J48` is a decision tree model (via RWeka). The code works (`doall(df1$DT_predict1, df2$DT_predict1)`) properly, I believe, because when I include the `return` function, it returns the values of `X1`. However, the predicted variables are not getting generated/stored in the data frames (df1 and df2). Ideally, I would like to have the dataframe names within the function, but that's the next step.

Can someone show how can I store the variables `X1` and `X2` within dataframes `df1` and `df2` respectively.

Comment: Was the answer below of any help, Andy? Please consider accepting or replying if you can (even at this late stage).

Answer (score 3):

Ideally your question would have a bit more information about what your data frames look like, what X1 and X2 look like, and where your data frames are stored. For my answer I am assuming your data frames are stored in the global environment, and you want to modify them through a function.

This question has to do with scoping. For an in-depth description of scoping check out this article http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

First, by assigning your variables within a function you are assigning them in a local environment. This means that the variables you are assigning do not carry over into the global environment (what you see when you type `ls()`.

I believe you either want change a 'global variable' from within a function. This is done by the

```
<<-
```

command

for instance

```
a <- 2
print(a)
```

returns `2`

```
change_a<-function(x){
        x<-x*4
}
change_a(a)
```

`print(a)`

still returns `2`

while

```
change_a<-function(x){
        x<<-x*4
}
change_a(a)
```

`print(a)`

would return `8`

I think you want to use the `<<-` operator instead of `<-` to accomplish what you want.

On a related note, it is not generally considered to be best practices to assign and change global variables from within a function.